# VLOOKUP not matching values and putting values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to use LOOKUP function for the following columns in one workbook: Sheet A contain ID and Sheet B has empID.

I am trying to compare both ID's i.e. ID from Sheet A and empID from Sheet B. If there is a match, I am putting the hourly rate in the column.

My VLOOKUP function looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;test;emp!M2;FALSE)
```

Where test is : `$A$2:$E$78`

Please find the excel file in the dropbox folder link.
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmvc4bfp9ngxt90/example.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) always looks up the **lookup_value** in the first column of the **table_array** and returns a value from a column to the left identified by a numerical **col_index_num**.

In Time_Spent!F2 as,

```
=VLOOKUP(B2; test1; 6; FALSE)
```

Note that your posted sample used a named range of **test1**, not **test** and test1 was =Employees!$A$2:$F$78, not =Employees!$A$2:$E$78. You cannot ask for the 6<sup>th</sup> column if you only supply 5.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. That was perfect. Unfortunately, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: No worries and don't take it to heart. We all get tunnel vision down the wrong path occasionally.